# can i store text file in java derby database?

Tags: java, derby

I want to store text files in java derby database and then from that data I want to plot some graph can I do that?(the text file contains ASCII data)

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these 3 methods to store the data

1. Store the contents of the file into a db column as text. Depending
   upon the data size either [CLOB](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefclob.html) or the [VARCHAR](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/crefsqlj31068.html) variants can
   be used.
2. Store the file as such into the database and use [BINARY](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefblob.html) data
   type. The file needs to be [binary read and stored](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/InsertBinaryDataintoaDatabaseTableUsingaStatement.htm).
3. Instead of storing the file or its data into the database just save the file in a folder and insert the filename with path into the database. Then select the filename back from the database and [read the contents directly from files the folder](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm).

The graph can be plot according to your requirement and the type of graph directly using [java code](https://www.java-forums.org/new-java/7995-how-plot-graph-java-given-samples.html) or a 3rd party library can also be used instead of reinventing the wheel.